# Char and Int printing two different values

Tags: c, char, printf

My code is reading a file containing integers:
3
2 1
2 2
2 3

```
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    if (fptr == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Cannot open file \n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    int c = fgetc(fptr); 
    printf("%c", c);

    fclose(fptr);
```

This is outputting the first number 3 as expected but when using it as an integer

```
printf("%d", c);
```

it outputs 51 instead? I'm trying to use these numbers as inputs for a counter and positions in a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

Your file doesn't contain the integers `3 2 1 2 2 2 3`.

- It contains a stream of bits
- Groups of 8 bits can be grouped together. These groupings are called bytes
- These bytes are interpreted by a *character
  encoding* (most likely ASCII or UTF-8), to represent the characters `3 2 1 2 2 2 3`.

A character encoding is a mapping between byte patterns and the characters they're associated with. For example, the UTF-8 states that `11111111 000000000 10011111 10011000 10000011` maps to the character Unicode character 1F603, "SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH": .

What you just saw is that the first byte of your file is `00110011`, which is the ASCI encoding for the character `'3'`.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are stored as integer according to an [encoding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Your system seems to use the [ASCII encoding set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Every single character has a respective ASCII code integer value, which determines how that character is stored in memory.

`'1'` has the ASCII value `49`, `'2'` the ASCII value `50` and `'3'` has the ASCII value `51`.

Here is a list of the standard ASCII set:

[image: ASCII-Table]

When you use `printf("%c", c);`, `c` is read as a character. As `c` holds the character `'3'`, it prints the character value `3`.

When you use `printf("%d", c);` instead, `c` is read as an integer and what is printed is not `3`, it is its relative ASCII code value, which is `51`.

> I'm trying to use these numbers as inputs for a counter and positions in a 2D array.

If you want to convert this character value to an integer, you can use `c - '0'` and assign it to another variable:

```
int c = fgetc(fptr); 
int i_c = c - '0';

printf("%d", i_c);
```

OR back to `c` again:

```
int c = fgetc(fptr); 
c = c - '0';

printf("%d", c);
```

Output in both cases:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading `3` as a character, .

In The system, following [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/), decimal value of `'3'` is `51`, so when you print the read value, it prints `51`

If you want the literal value, you can use something like

```
 printf("%d", c- '0');
```

as the numbers `0` to `9` are bound to have strictly increasing serial values in encoding.

Comment: Or just stick with %c. That's what it's there for in the first place. Why jump through not-really-portable hoops?